# Is it haram to call yourself a god of something? Please read

Tags: allah, halal-haram, blasphemy

This is in the context of calling yourself a god, for example. If i am very good at football and call myself a god of football will this be haram? I am not calling myself allah, instead if i call myself as very skilled. This is very important for me to know as I own a large instagram page containg the word god in that context. If it is haram I’d like to do the right thing and sell or change the name. Please help me because i dont want to get sins. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure its haram to call anything but Allah a god because its shirk. God means something to worship, we should only worship Allah. Allah is the only god. Calling an object or a person a god is haram basically because the meaning of the word god means something thats worshipped. Thats all i can say from my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

**I will try to answer this using an analogy**

Muslims use attributes of Allah to name their children at times. Yet such names are prefixed with the 'Abd' (for males) roughly translating to 'slave'.

So even when using God's attributes one is careful and prefers to prefix to be called Abdur Rahman or Abdul Gaffar rather than just Rahman or Gaffar, it is more benefiting the Muslims to avoid calling themselves God of anything.

In places like India, I have heard people calling sportsman (Sachin Tendulkar) or actors (Rajnikanth) as God of thier fields even tough the individuals themselves avoid to do so. But today we have temples built with their idols in it due to the ignorance of their fans.

I hope that answer your question.

Salaam

Answer (score 0):

you are commiting shirk a major sin you need to take the shahada again and believing it that “there is no god but allah and muhammad is the messenger of allah” you need to make repentence by doing tawbah. Its best to get ur answers from a mufti as the other guy clearly lied to you.

Answer (score -1):

It's not haram because the *intention* is not describe yourself really as God. It's merely being used as a superlative. This is already understood in ordinary and conventional usage of the English language.

This may not be the case in other languages, say Arabic. In which case there, I'd advise caution. Nevertheless, notice it's quite common to use names that derive from the attributes of Allah without the implication that one actually is an attribute of Allah.